# How to list the contents of a zipped uploaded to google drive folder using API?

Tags: api, google-drive-api, zip

Many large zip-files are uploaded to my google drive. Before downloading I need to preview this zip-archive for understanding what files are in it.

On Google Drive website I can preview zip-archive and see files\directories list.

Is it possible if I use Google Drive API?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: To my knowledge, I don't think we can list the contents of a zip file saved in Google drive using the API.